# Update MongoDB collection with values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I need to update all documents in a MongoDB collection with values from an array.

Say for example i have the documents in below schema in mongo:

```
{
 "key":"value",
 "key2":"value2"
}
```

I have an array : ["test","test2"]

I want to create an iterator through the array, so the "keyN" key in all docs in the collections are updated with either "test" or "test2"

```
{
  "key":"value",
  "key2":"value2",
  "keyN":"test"
}
{
  "key":"value",
  "key2":"value2",
  "keyN":"test2"
}
{
  "key":"value",
  "key2":"value2",
  "keyN":"test"
}
```

How do I do this? I tried using the forEach, but I am not able to figure out the way to create an iterator on the array.

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: I edited the original question. I just wan to know how to do this? Iterating through the array is fine, but at the end of the array, how do I go back to the first element?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for...here is a piece of test using mongoose schema not the actual mongodb document.

Mark the answer as correct or let me know if the test/code needs any improvement.

[image: Mocha Test result]

**Mocha Test file**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect,mongooseMock = require('mongoose-
mock'),proxyquire=require('proxyquire'),
sinon = require('sinon'), chai=require('chai'),sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");chai.use(sinonChai);

var AIterator;
describe('model', function() {
        beforeEach(function (done) {
                AIterator = proxyquire('./ArrayIterator', {'mongoose': mongooseMock});                done();   
        });
it("should iterate the array",function(done){
        setTimeout(done, 15000);
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        var aIterator =[];
        aIterator[0]= AIterator.create({"key":"value1","key2":"value2","keyN":"value3"}, callback);
        aIterator[1]= AIterator.create({"key":"value4","key2":"value5","keyN":"value6"}, callback);
        aIterator[2]= AIterator.create({"key":"value7","key2":"value8","keyN":"value9"}, callback);
        var x=0;
         aIterator.forEach(function(element) {
                if (element.keyN=="value9")
                {
                element.keyN="test";        
                }                 
         }, this);
        expect(aIterator[2].keyN).equals("value3");
        done(); 
});
});
```

**Code file**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var arraySchema = new Schema({
  key:String,
  key2:String,
  keyN:String
});

var NewArray = new mongoose.Schema(arraySchema);
NewArray.statics.create = function (params, callback) {
  var newUpdate = new NewArray(params);
  newUpdate.save(function(err, result) {
    callback(err, result);
  });
  return newUpdate;
};
var ArrayIterator = mongoose.model('Model', NewArray);
module.exports = ArrayIterator;
```

Or,

another test to run the values in the input array, if this is what you meant:

```
it("should iterate the array",function(done){
        setTimeout(done, 15000);
        var callback = sinon.spy();
        var testArray=["test","test1"];
        var aIterator =[];
        aIterator[0]= AIterator.create({"key":"value1","key2":"value2","keyN":"value3"}, callback);
        aIterator[1]= AIterator.create({"key":"value4","key2":"value5","keyN":"value6"}, callback);
        aIterator[2]= AIterator.create({"key":"value7","key2":"value8","keyN":"value9"}, callback);
        var x=0;
        testArray.forEach(function(element){
                if (element=="test")
                {
                 aIterator.forEach(function(element1) {
                 if (element1.keyN=="value9")
                 {
                   element1.keyN=element;        
                        }                 
                }, this);
                }
                 },this);
        expect(aIterator[2].keyN).equals("value3");
        done(); 
});
```